# Interface netduino with Iphone via audio jack

Tags: netduino, iphone, bus

I am interested in making the netduino establish a BUS connection to the IPhone via the audio jack. Does anyone have any experience doing this? I have read a few things online...but I am somewhat lost.

Comment: At which point are you lost? Hardware; software; both? Do you mean something specific by "BUS"?

Comment: I would say both... when i say BUS i mean communication bus...to transfer data.

Comment: What is the state of your software on the iPhone?  Can you get a microphone reading from the iPhone, or set a voltage on the headphone pins?  Until you're there, this isn't really an electronics problem.  Ask at http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 7):

There is a project developed by David Jurick, Adam Stolarz, Damien Stolarz that is described in the book [iPhone Hacks](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516642/). They use the audio jack as a Frequency Shift Keying (FSK) modem that operates at about 1200 baud. Their project interfaces with a Cypress PSoC microcontroller to convert the audio signal to RS232. [Source Code](http://www.perceptdev.com/labs/iphonehacks) can be found at the www.perceptdev.com site.

A similar project using an Arduino to convert the signal can be found [here](http://sree.cc/iphone/iphone-as-temperature-detector).

Another project called [HiJack](http://eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/projects/hijack/) harvests power and bandwidth from the iPhone's audio jack.

Comment: Now to combine power harvesting and bidirectional data connection... :)

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino CPU might be able to handle bidirectional BPSK at a low enough baud rate.