# Data communication via audio channel

Tags: arduino, audio

I am planning to send data from a sensor to a mobile phone(such as iPhone) via mobile phone's trs connection(via audio jack). Since i have to use the audio channel, i need to convert the analogue signals to digital before sending to iPhone.

Does anybody have knowledge how can i achieve this in a simple way? 
What kind of micro controller and circuit components i should use?

I was planning to use Arduino as a micro controller.
Some claims it happens by using FSK or Manchester encoding.

I need a simple schematics diagram for that, which i could not find.

Comment: Why do you need to convert analogue signals to digital when audio input is analogue in the first place? Are you sure you don't want to convert digital signals to analogue?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8163/interface-netduino-with-iphone-via-audio-jack

Comment: i am dealing with this part. i want to send the data to the software in the mobile phone. all the current papers are saying to convert to manchester code or fsk before sending to software. i dont know why.

Comment: i can not find circuit schematics. they just share the code:(

Comment: @cmd1024 People might be more motivated to answer your questions if you accepted answers.  You've asked 14 questions and have not accepted answers to any of them.

Comment: @cmd1024 David mentioned an interesting point. I've seen a good number of your questions and as far as I can see, you haven't mentioned why the answers provided do not solve questions you asked. If some answers solve the question, click on the green tick mark next to them. Otherwise indicate why they don't help and what you need.

Comment: guys i am not even aware of this fact, i will be more careful. i have serious loss in my left eye. soemtimes i do not notice.

Comment: Another issue here is that we are not going to just hand over a schematic to you nor will we tell you what microcontroller to use. All of this is far too broad. Start on your project and ask specific design questions rather then broad level brainstorming and "give me the schematic" questions.

Comment: Questions: What type of sensor is it? What is the output of the sensor (An analogue voltage? What voltage range?) What sample rate do you require?

Comment: for example i want to use an ultrasonic sensor. i think i need fsk for that? the point is i want to make it with an atmel chip. since i already have arduino so i can program it.

Comment: You might actually be able to connect the pulse output of the ultrasonic sensor straight to the line-in of the iPhone. Then you'll just need to measure the pulse width on the iPhone. The point is that the iPhone inputs might have DC blocking capacitors, so slowly varying voltages won't get through, but the ultrasonic pulses might,

Comment: @cmd1024 Please edit your question with all relevant information. We shouldn't have to read through the comments to figure out what you are doing. Your approach should be, describe your problem in detail and explain what you have attempted to do and why you need our help.

Comment: thanks, another point i am only dealing with that part. i have no knowledge about iphone sdk. how can i understand that the pulses are delivered? is there a way to do that?

Comment: iphone SDK will be off-topic here. We will help you with the electronics side, but you have got to meet us half way and do the things we are talking about in comments.

Comment: Also, please get to accepting some answers. You were told many times on prior questions and then again here. If you aren't happy with the answer then explain what isn't being answered. Accepting an answer is like saying "Thank you, your answer helped me a lot". If you don't accept any, it is like you never thank anyone. If you never thank anyone, why would they want to help you again?

Comment: what do you mean by accept? where is that option? i will do that but i couldnt see that?

Comment: @cmd1024 Go to a different question of yours and look at the answers.  On the left will be two arrows, one up and one down.  Under it will be a circle with a check-mark.  Pick the best answer for your question and click on the circle with check-mark.  It will turn green when you have selected it.  Give your question a day or three before doing this to give everyone a chance to answer, although you can change which answer you have accepted if you want.  Just click on a different answer's check-mark.

Comment: @cmd1024  This is documented in the FAQ, here:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FSK (Frequency Shift Keying) is one option, though ASK (Amplitude Shift Keying) is easier. The reason why FSK is more popular is that it's less noise sensitive than ASK. Compare with FM and AM in radio transmission; FM also offers better quality. Since you want to transfer sensor data the required bandwidth might be low, and ASK may work satisfactory.

To generate ASK make an oscillator whose output level you can switch through a switchable voltage divider. To demodulate the signal a simple envelope detector

[image]

followed by a comparator may be all you need. All depends on the required data bandwidth, which you don't mention in your question.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the demodulator would be possible to implement inside the iPhone.